# use :tjump instead of :tag vim on pressing ctrl-]

Tags: tags, vim, tagging, ctags

in vim,
when i press `ctrl-]`

1) the usual behavior:
it goes to the first matching tag with the word under the cursor,
after that we need to do `:tjump` separately to see a list of all matching tags and then jump to the desired tag.

2) what i want is:
vim should search the tag file,
   if there are multiple matches, show me a list of all the matching tags
   if there is one match, simply jump to the matching tag
   (just like `:tjump` does)

this behavior(2) already happens when we use `g-ctrl-]`, but i want it to happen with `ctrl-]`
i have seen behavior(2) using `ctrl-]` in some vims in some linuses.

please tell me how i can obtain behavior(2). in other words,
please tell me how i can make `ctrl-]` to behave like `g-ctrl-]` using *.vimrc* or whatever

Answer (score 15):

This will map `<c-]>` to `g<c-]>` for both normal and visual modes.

```
nnoremap <c-]> g<c-]>
vnoremap <c-]> g<c-]>
```

I suggest you map `g<c-]>` to `<c-]>`. In other words just swap the commands.

```
nnoremap g<c-]> <c-]>
vnoremap g<c-]> <c-]>
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. that solved it.. mapping <c-]> to g<c-]> worked. put it in vimrc

Comment: how can you also map <Ctrl> + left-mouse click to use behavior(2) instead of behavior(1)?
Could I simply map tag to tjump?

Comment: `nnoremap <c-leftmouse> g<c-]>`. However I recommend using keyboard as it is the vim way.

Comment: I have trouble seeing how behavior(1) is useful in all but very rare occasions, in which case it's better to just press `1<enter>` rather than struggle to remember to prefix the command with `g`. Hence, unless someone convinces me otherwise, I won't bother with `[nv]noremove g<c-]> <c-]>` in my config